# Is there a way in HTML with php to move between and use several modals

Tags: php, html, forms, modal-dialog

I am creating a Login modal which will include a few modals for registration, logout and update registration. What is an effective way to handle all the modals?
My HTML main page is “index.php” which is as follows.

```
<?php
/*
 *  Programming Title Block
*/
…
    include('account/registration/login_code.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <?php include("view/head.php"); ?>
    </head>
    <body class='homePage_bg'>
        <?php include("view/header.php"); ?>
        <?php include("view/nav.php"); ?>
        <div class="content">
            <?php include('account/registration/login.php'); ?>
        <article>
…
        </article>
        </div>
        <?php include("view/footer.php"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The login.php file needs some more work but currently looks like this:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id='id01' class='modal'>
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'"
        class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    <!-- Modal Content -->
    <form class="modal-content animate" method='post' action=''>
        <div class='modal-header'>
            <h2>Member Login</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <label><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Name</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' name='username' />
            <label><i class="fas fa-lock"></i> Password</label>
            <input type='password' class='form-control' name='password' />
        </div>
        <div class='modal-footer'>
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' name='login' data-dismiss='modal' value='Login' />
            <input type='button' class='btn btn-primary' name='cancel' value='Cancel' 
                     onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" />
        </div>
    </form>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
</script>
</div>
```

The “index_code.php” file is as follows:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }
/*
 *  Programming Title Block
 */

    require_once('model/name_db.php');

    $dbna = new dbName();

    $_SESSION['$Registration_ID'] = null;
    unset($_SESSION['$Registration_ID']);

    if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'login')) {
        // username and password sent from form
        $userName = "'" . filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username') . "'";
        $password = "'" . filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password') . "'";

        try {
            list($name, $message1) = $dbna->get_name_by_userName_and_password($userName, $password);
            $message .= $message1;
            if(!$name) {
                $message .= "There was no matching User-Name and Password.";
            }
            else {
                $_SESSION["RegName_ID"] = $_SESSION["Name_ID"] = $nameID = $name['name_id'];
                $_SESSION["Security_ID"] = $name['security_id'];
                $_SESSION["fullName"] = $full_Name = $name['namefull'];
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            $message .= $sql . "<br />" . $e->getMessage().'<br />';
        }
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

Previously I had a Login.php file at the same level as the main page index.php. In that file I included these php includes in the php section and HTML section of coding.

```
<?php
…
include 'account/registration/LoginIndex_code.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
…
<?php include 'account/registration/LoginIndex.php'; ?>
…
The 'account/registration/LoginIndex.php' was as follows:
<?php //
/* 
 * Programming Title Block
 */
if(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action')) {
    $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
}
switch ($action) {
    case 'login':
        include('login.php');
        break;
    case 'regName':
        include('regName.php');
        break;
    case 'regAddress':
        include('regAddress.php');
        break;
…
```

The problem with the previous code was I was using the URL action variable to update the state of the login mode. Thus the modal was not acting as a modal but rather an HTML web page. Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the nav.php file to be able to Login and pull-down menu for Logout and Update Registration.

```
...
<?php if(!$full_Name){ ?>
                <a class="btn rightBtn" id='login'
                   onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" >Login</a>
<?php } else { ?>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Logout
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a class="btn rightBtn" id='logout'
                            onclick="document.getElementById('id99').style.display='block'" >Logout</a>
                        <a class="btn" href="Login.php?action=updateName">Update Name</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
<?php } ?>
...
```

The login modal now includes the option to Sign-Up

```
...
        <div class='modal-footer'>
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' name='login' data-dismiss='modal' value='Login' />
            <input type='button' class='btn' name='cancel' value='Cancel' 
                     onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" />
            <input type='button' class='btn' name='signup' value='Sign-Up' 
                     onclick="location.href='Login.php?action=regName'" />
        </div>
...
```

In summary, every page of the website now includes code for modals to login and logout, which the state is toggled to display or none display by the the onclick control.
The Registration and Update Registration is indexed by a switch statement and related code is called into the Login.php file at root. The switch statement reads the action of the URL.